# Python Pandas merge only certain columns

Tags: python, merge, pandas

Is it possible to only merge some columns? I have a DataFrame df1 with columns x, y, z, and df2 with columns x, a ,b, c, d, e, f, etc.

I want to merge the two DataFrames on x, but I only want to merge columns df2.a, df2.b - not the entire DataFrame.

The result would be a DataFrame with x, y, z, a, b.

I could merge then delete the unwanted columns, but it seems like there is a better method.

Comment: Andy: Holy cow that was easy...I need a break, I'm obviously making this too complicated. Thanks for the clarity!

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You could merge the sub-DataFrame (with just those columns):

```
df2[list('xab')]  # df2 but only with columns x, a, and b

df1.merge(df2[list('xab')])
```

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if there should be a native way to do this, like subset in dropna... will put together github issue

Comment: Hmmm ... I tried using this to merge column 'Unique_External_Users' from df2 to df1 but got an error ... "None of [Index(['U', 'n', 'i', 'q', 'u', 'e', '_', 'E', 'x', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a',\n       'l', '_', 'U', 's', 'e', 'r', 's'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" .

Comment: Here's the code . ... df1.merge(df2('Unique_External_Users')])

Comment: @CoolDocMan I think you missed something from the proposed answer:
`list('xab')` takes each element (letter) of the string 'xab' and converts it to a list element so `list('xab')` returns `['x', 'a', 'b']`. That works if each column has a single letter as a name. In your case I think you need to do df1.merge(df2['Unique_External_Users'], *other_arguments).
...Most probably you already solved it by now, just leaving this for newbies around, like me

Answer (score 285):

You want to use TWO brackets, so if you are doing a VLOOKUP sort of action:

```
df = pd.merge(df,df2[['Key_Column','Target_Column']],on='Key_Column', how='left')
```

This will give you everything in the original df + add that one corresponding column in df2 that you want to join.

Comment: Can `Target_Column` be a list of columns?

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer. @BubbleGuppies

Comment: @Gathide Yes, there can be multiple target columns like `df2[['key','target1','target2']]`

Comment: What are df, 'Key_Column','Target_Column' , why the answer is not in terms of the question?

Answer (score 48):

If you want to drop column(s) from the target data frame, but the column(s) are required for the join, you can do the following:

```py
df1 = df1.merge(df2[['a', 'b', 'key1']], how = 'left',
                left_on = 'key2', right_on = 'key1').drop(columns = ['key1'])
```

The `.drop(columns = 'key1')` part will prevent 'key1' from being kept in the resulting data frame, despite it being required to join in the first place.

Comment: I get the following error if I try this: `KeyError: "['key1'] not found in axis"`

Comment: try .drop(columns= ['key1'])

Comment: Or .drop('key1', axis = 1)

Comment: or shorter: `.drop('key1', 1)`

Comment: Very good point. This is different than in SQL where you can `SELECT df1..., df1.,, df2.a, df2.b FROM df1 LEFT JOIN df2 ON df1.key2=df2.key1`  (whereby not needed to selecting either `df1.key2` or `df2.key1`)

Also good idea to replace the original df1 with the new df1 so that this will simply add new columns based on merge.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `.loc` to select the specific columns with all rows and then pull that. An example is below:

```
pandas.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2.iloc[:, [0:5]], how='left', on='key')
```

In this example, you are merging dataframe1 and dataframe2. You have chosen to do an outer left join on 'key'. However, for dataframe2 you have specified `.iloc` which allows you to specific the rows and columns you want in a numerical format. Using `:`, your selecting all rows, but `[0:5]` selects the first 5 columns. You could use `.loc` to specify by name, but if your dealing with long column names, then `.iloc` may be better.

Comment: Beware that [`.loc` will make a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy), and on a large df that can be painful. It might be better to merge then immediately take a column slice in the same expression.

Answer (score 9):

This is to merge selected columns from two tables.

If `table_1` contains `t1_a,t1_b,t1_c..,id,..t1_z` columns,
and `table_2` contains `t2_a, t2_b, t2_c..., id,..t2_z` columns,
and only t1_a, id, t2_a are required in the final table, then

```
mergedCSV = table_1[['t1_a','id']].merge(table_2[['t2_a','id']], on = 'id',how = 'left')
# save resulting output file    
mergedCSV.to_csv('output.csv',index = False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Slight extension of the accepted answer for multi-character column names, using inner join by default:

```py
df1 = df1.merge(df2[["Key_Column", "Target_Column1", "Target_Column2"]])
```

This assumes that `Key_Column` is the only column both dataframes have in common.