# Looking for specifics records matchs in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have df1 as follow:

```
Name    |  ID
________|_____
Banana  |  10
Orange  |  21
Peach   |  115
```

Then I have a df2 like this:

```
ID   Price
10    2.34
10    2.34
115   6.00
```

I want to modify df2 to add another column name Fruit to get this as output:

```
 ID   Fruit     Price
 10   Banana    2.34
 10   Banana    2.34
 115  Peach     6.00
 200  NA        NA
```

I can use iloc to get one specific match but how to do it in all records in the df2?

Comment: so basically ``pd.merge``?

Comment: how you are getting ID='200' in your expected output?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,how='outer',on='ID')`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function ?

```
pd.merge(df1, df2)
```

Output :

```
    Name    Id  Price
0   Banana  10  2.34
1   Banana  10  2.34
2   Peach   115 6.00
```

**EDIT :**
If you want to add only a specific column from df2  :

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2[['Id','Price']],on='Id', how='left')
```

Output :

```
Name    Id  Price
0   Banana  10  2.34
1   Banana  10  2.34
2   Orange  21  NaN
3   Peach   115 6.00
```

Comment: I'll try.  df1 has 33 columns and df2 has 17.  I just want to add one more column in df2.  Merge will do this, right?

Comment: If you only want to merge 1 column from df2 into df1, you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978133/python-pandas-merge-only-certain-columns) question. I'll edit my answer.