# Merge two dataframes with id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframes. But when I do the following I got `KeyError: "['available'] not in index"`. I looked at [Python Pandas merge only certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978133/python-pandas-merge-only-certain-columns) .  But what I'm doing wrong?

```py
d = { 'listing_id': [1,2,3,4],
      'month': [1, 2, 3, 4],
      'price': [79.00, 80.00, 90.00, 20.00]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
     'available': [5000, 8000,5000, 7000],
     'someotherstuff': [2,3,4,5]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

df = pd.merge(df,df2[['id','available']],on='listing_id', how='left')

What I want

  listing_id  month  price   available 
0           1      1   79.0  5000
1           2      2   80.0  8000
2           3      3   90.0  5000
3           4      4   20.0  7000
```

Comment: ``available`` column name has space at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling pandas to merge, `on = 'listing_id'`, but do not have a `listing_id` in `df2`.

Change the `id` to `listing_id` and this should work. Also, no need to specify what columns you want to merge (no need for `df2[['id','available']]`.

```
d = { 'listing_id': [1,2,3,4],
      'month': [1, 2, 3, 4],
      'price': [79.00, 80.00, 90.00, 20.00]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df['listing_id'])

d2 = {'listing_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
     'available ': [5000, 8000,5000, 7000]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

df = pd.merge(df,df2,on = 'listing_id', how='left')
print(df)
```

The output:

```
Name: listing_id, dtype: int64
   listing_id  month  price  available 
0           1      1   79.0        5000
1           2      2   80.0        8000
2           3      3   90.0        5000
3           4      4   20.0        7000
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution won't work because your ID columns have different names. Try this:

`df = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='listing_id', right_on='id')`

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. And how could I only merge certian columns?

Comment: `df[certain_columns].merge(df2[other_certain_columns], left_on=...)`.

Comment: Or if you're only excluding a small number of columns, just chain `.drop('id', axis = 1, inplace=True)` to your merge.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly there is an extra space in your column `available`, so [`strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) that out.

```
df2.columns
Out[10]: Index(['id', 'available '], dtype='object')

df2.columns = [col.strip() for col in df2.columns]
Out[15]: Index(['id', 'available'], dtype='object')
```

Then, your column that you want the merge to happen on is called differently in the two dataframes, so you need to specify `left_on =`  and `right_on =`  in the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) command:

```
pd.merge(df,df2[['id','available']],left_on='listing_id', right_on = 'id',how='left').drop('id',axis=1)

   listing_id  month  price  available
0           1      1   79.0       5000
1           2      2   80.0       8000
2           3      3   90.0       5000
3           4      4   20.0       7000
```